# Numpy array row is split over 2 lines. Can this be changed?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, jupyter-notebook

I need to create a 12 x 12 numpy array . However from the 6th value onward , jupyter notebook is pushing the array onto the next line.I appreciate this is only a visual thing and that my array will work correctly , its just makes it very difficult for checking when one row spans two lines.

Cheers ,

Ross

[image]

"edit" the following has been added `np.set_printoptions(linewidth=np.inf)` . All but one of the values is on a single line now. can i reduce the spacing between the values .

[Updated array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJc8o.png)

"edit"

found a work around . set line width to inf and round values to 1 dp.

Comment: Round then print?

Comment: Here's some help you can find on how to display properly on jupyter notebook.... https://songhuiming.github.io/pages/2017/04/02/jupyter-and-pandas-display/

Comment: I think the original splitting is `numpy's`, the second is jupyter's.